# Cannot understand this identity between kronecker and metric tensor

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, group-theory

I'm working on Lorentz generators and I am really not able to understand this relation:

$$\omega_{\rho \sigma} \eta^{\rho\mu} \delta^{\alpha}_{\nu} = \frac{1}{2}\omega_{\rho \sigma} \left(\eta^{\rho\mu} \delta^{\sigma}_{\nu} - \eta^{\sigma\mu}\delta^{\rho}_{\nu}\right)$$

I tried to write it expanded:

$$\omega_{\rho \sigma} \eta^{\rho\mu} \delta^{\alpha}_{\nu} = \frac{1}{2}\omega_{\rho \sigma}\eta^{\rho\mu} \delta^{\sigma}_{\nu} -\frac{1}{2}\omega_{\rho \sigma} \eta^{\sigma\mu}\delta^{\rho}_{\nu}$$

The only thing that comes up in my mind is that $\omega$ are antisymmetric, hence $\omega_{\rho\sigma} = -\omega_{\sigma\rho}$ but then I would get

$$\omega_{\rho \sigma} \eta^{\rho\mu} \delta^{\alpha}_{\nu} = \frac{1}{2}\omega_{\rho \sigma}\eta^{\rho\mu} \delta^{\sigma}_{\nu} + \frac{1}{2}\omega_{\sigma \rho} \eta^{\sigma\mu}\delta^{\rho}_{\nu}$$

I don't think it's that easy though. Also I still have problems with understanding the difference between

$$g^{\rho\mu}\qquad  \text{VS} \qquad g^{\mu\rho}$$

Using indexes it's such a hard thing!

Comment: If you are going to ask a question like this you need to be careful not to make typos. For example, your first equation has an $\alpha$ on the LHS but not on the RHS... Is that a typo?

Comment: Let me at least try to address your last point - *most* metrics $g$ are symmetric in their indices, so that means $g^{\rho\mu}=g^{\mu\rho}$. Think of it like a diagonal matrix (which it is....roughly.....).

Comment: Oh, and tell us more about what $\omega$ and $\eta$ are as well. When I see them I go "spin connection and Minkowski metric", but others might have different responses, and you want us to know what you mean.

Comment: Assuming you mean $\alpha=\sigma$ on the left-hand side, your  right-hand one *needs* to trace $\omega_{\rho\sigma}$, a tensor antisymmetric in $\rho\sigma$,   with one such also antisymmetric in $\rho\sigma$, so as not to vanish! That is, the  $\rho\sigma$ symmetric piece of the l.h.s. is projected out by $\omega_{\rho\sigma}$, and hence is absent.

Comment: Antisymmetric generator parameter, and Minkowski metric (symmetric), respectively. Your text fails to specify that? Doubtful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mistyped and $\alpha$ is actually meant to be $\sigma$, then you obtain this relation as follows:

\begin{align*}\omega_{\rho \sigma} \eta^{\rho\mu} \delta^{\sigma}_{\nu} &= \frac{1}{2} \Big( 2 \cdot \omega_{\rho \sigma} \eta^{\rho\mu} \delta^{\sigma}_{\nu} \Big) \\
&{} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \Big( \omega_{\rho \sigma} \eta^{\rho\mu} \delta^{\sigma}_{\nu} + \omega_{\rho \sigma} \eta^{\rho\mu} \delta^{\sigma}_{\nu} \Big) \\
&{} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \Big( \omega_{\rho \sigma} \eta^{\rho\mu} \delta^{\sigma}_{\nu} - \omega_{\sigma \rho } \eta^{\rho\mu} \delta^{\sigma}_{\nu} \Big) \tag{by antisymmetry of $\omega$}
\end{align*}

Since $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are just dummy indices, i.e. they are summed over and can be named any way you want, we rename them in the second term, such that the original $\rho$ is now called $\sigma$ and the original $\sigma$ is now called $\rho$. This yields

\begin{align*}\phantom{\omega_{\rho \sigma} \eta^{\rho\mu} \delta^{\sigma}_{\nu}}&= \frac{1}{2} \Big( \omega_{\rho \sigma} \eta^{\rho\mu} \delta^{\sigma}_{\nu} - \omega_{\rho \sigma} \eta^{\sigma \mu} \delta^{\rho}_{\nu} \Big) \\
&{} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \omega_{\rho \sigma} \Big( \eta^{\rho\mu} \delta^{\sigma}_{\nu} - \eta^{\sigma \mu} \delta^{\rho}_{\nu} \Big)
\end{align*}

which is the relation in question.